# Getting errors in loading a command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

So I am building a bot.
Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="&")
token = "<token censored for privacy>"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} has connected to Discord.")

@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx, args):
    await ctx.send(args*10)
    await ctx.send("You got rolled. Do it again.")

bot.add_command(repeat)
client.run(token)
```

But when I run the code, I get back an error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command repeat is already an existing command or alias.`

I have not called the `bot.add_command` function before. Can anyone help out with this?
Screenshot of the error:
[discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWKky.png)

Screenshot of the code:
[bot.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BARxL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to add a command to your bot, you have two options.

- You can add the `@bot.command()` decorator, or
- You can use the `@commands.command()` decorator and run `bot.add_command(repeat)`

Both of these will add your command to the bot. Take a look at the `discord.py` [documentation for commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) for more details about adding commands.

The reason you're seeing the error is that you actually are adding the command twice.